# Fill up array with pages wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a page for products on my website and I have an array to store all of the pages that have products as a parent. This works fine but for some reason, it stops filling up the array after 10 entries. This is my code to fill up the array.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => get_page_by_path( 'products' )->ID,
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any');    

// The Query
$parent = new WP_Query( $args );
$n = 0;
// The Loop
if ( $parent->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $parent->have_posts() ) {
        $parent->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        $n++;
        echo $n;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This returns the titles of the Pages and echo's a number to count them. The output shows the titles but stops after `10 pages`, even though I have `12 pages` with products as a parent. The strange thing is that when I add another page with products as a parent it pushes the last one in the list out and puts the newly added one in the first spot in the array. 
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `posts_per_page` instead of `numberposts`.

```
$args = array(
'post_parent' => get_page_by_path( 'products' )->ID,
'post_type'   => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_status' => 'any');
```

Comment: Need to wait 10 mins to be able to accept an answer, but I will :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define how many posts are returned by setting `posts_per_page` in your `$args` array.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => get_page_by_path( 'products' )->ID,
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => '100');
```